# How can I check if an element in a list exists more than certain times

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if an item (e.g. a role in a football match) exists more than certain times. for example with a for loop I want to insert a role to add to a list, so my if condition checks in the list if the attack role already exists 2 times, if it already exists I have to insert another role, otherwise it can say it

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp

Comment: Please share your code, whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-do-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on the context but here are two ways of doing this:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']

x = fruits.count("cherry")
>>>x
1
```

or with a dictionary method that stores the count of each element

```
from collections import Counter
x = Counter(['apple','red','apple','red','red','pear'])
>>>x
Counter({'red': 3, 'apple': 2, 'pear': 1})
```

you can access each of the separate elements

```
x['red']
>>>3
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought `collections` in Python can help with your use case.

```
import collections

l = ['a', 'a', 'd', 'd']
c = collections.Counter(l)
print(c["a"])

# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an example:

```
#your list of items
footballRoles = ["attack", "defensive", "goalkeeper", "full-backs", "defensive"]

searchValue = input("Enter the role name you want to add to the list: ")
    
# the "searchValueCounter" is the container for certain times you are looking for in your list so if you want to know if the "attack" role exists for two times then you store here how many times you want to check 
searchValueCounter = 2


#the method count() shows you how many times the role you are looking for appears in the list
#-----Before add
print(footballRoles)
counter = footballRoles.count(searchValue)
print(counter)

if counter < searchValueCounter:
    footballRoles.append(searchValue)
elif counter == searchValueCounter:
    footballRoles.append(input("Enter another role: "))

#-----After add
print(footballRoles)
counter = footballRoles.count(searchValue)
print(counter)
```

I wish this code insight you.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code so you understand:

```
class Squad():
    FinalSquad = []
    def __init__(self, name, role, number):
        self.name = name
        self.role = role
        self.number = number

    def formazione(self):
        Squad.FinalSquad.append(self.name)

squad = []
roles = ["attack", "center", "defense", "goalkeeper"]
temp = []
numbers = []
players = 2

for i in range(players):
    giocatore = input("Insert player name: ")
    while giocatore in squad:
        giocatore = input("Player name already selected, try again: ")
    squad.append(giocatore)

    RoleSelect = input("Insert a role: ")
    while (RoleSelect == "attack") and (RoleSelect in temp > 2) or (RoleSelect == "center") and (RoleSelect in temp > 4) or (RoleSelect == "defense") and (RoleSelect in temp > 4) or (RoleSelect == "goalkeeper") and (RoleSelect in temp > 1) or (RoleSelect not in roles):
        RoleSelect = input("Role not avaible, try again: ")
    temp.append(RoleSelect)

    NumberSelect = int(input("Insert player number: "))
    while NumberSelect in numbers:
        int(input("player number already selected, try again: "))
    numbers.append(NumberSelect)

    Squad(giocatore, RoleSelect, NumberSelect)
```